# Error: The client specified not to prompt but the user is not logged in

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, okta

I am trying to retrieve some content on a website that requires okta (oauth2) authentication. In order to make the request that will give me that data, an okta code is required. However, when I try to make the python request to the endpoint that will serve me that code, I receive the error message in the title. This is the function I am using:

```
def authorizeNonce(session, authNoncePayload): #Returns the okta code I need

nonce          = authNoncePayload["nonce"]
client_id      = authNoncePayload["client_id"]
code_challenge = authNoncePayload["code_challenge"]
state          = authNoncePayload["state"]
stateToken     = authNoncePayload["stateToken"]

URL = f"https://id.example-website.org/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?nonce={nonce}&response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://ident.example-website.org/sso/oauth2c/OAuthProxy.jsp&scope=openid%20profile&code_challenge={code_challenge}&code_challenge_method=S256&state={state}&prompt=none"

headers = {
    #some headers extracted from browser developer tools
}

response = session.get(URL, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
code = re.search("(?<=code=)([A-Z0-9]*)", response.headers["location"]).group(1)

return code
```

This is the output of my error when I print the 'location' value from response.headers:

```
location:  https://ident.example-website.org/sso/oauth2c/OAuthProxy.jsp?state=tndykvamx5bexample5e2tat&error=login_required&error_description=The+client+specified+not+to+prompt%2C+but+the+user+is+not+logged+in.
```

The okta code should be located in response.headers["location"], but when I print that I get the error message. Of course this works properly when I use hardcoded cookies from an opened session in the browser. However, I need to use this through command line, since this is for automation purposes.

I also find this weird, since I'm using the same session object to get all the previous values (nonce, client_id, code_challenge, etc), considering that, I don't understand why okta says that I have no active sessions.